# Efficient way of s4 object in R ?

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm trying to define schools with identifiers and some other parameters and classes in each school with identifiers and some other parameters and students and teacher for each class. I defined S4 objects for each type. i.e.

```
student <- setClass(
      "student",   
         slots = c(
            identifier = "numeric",   
            testscore = "numeric",
            endAbil = "numeric"
         )  
) 

clss <- setClass(
     "class",  
         slots = c(
             identifier = "numeric",
             teacher = "teacher",
             student = "student",   
             capacity = "numeric"
          )  
 )

   school <- setClass(
          "school",   
           slots = c(
                identifier = "numeric",                     
                cls = "matrix",
                capacity = "numeric"
            )  
   )
```

My question is after I assign students to schools and classes randomly if I change a value of student it just change the value inside of schools. Is there a way to link those values to students and if we change a value of i th  schools' j th class students' variable it will also change variable of students.

```
  Students <- new("student", identifier = sample('#ofStudents'))  
  Students@endAbil <-rnorm('#ofStudents',mean = 0 , sd = 1)

  # Randomly assign students to classes 

  ind = 1:'#ofStudents'
  #  #ofClasses is fixed for all schools

  for (i in 1:'#ofSchools'){
    for (j in 1:'#ofClasses'){
        # get the ith schools' jth class

        tmp <- sample(ind,Schools@cls[i,j][[1]]@capacity)      
        Schools@cls[i,j][[1]]@student@identifier <- Students@identifier[tmp]
        Schools@cls[i,j][[1]]@student@endAbil <- Students@endAbil[tmp]
        ind = ind [! ind %in% tmp]
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

R has copy on change semantics rather than reference semantics, so the operation you wish to do is not generally the preferred or 'natural' way. You could investigate so-called reference classes, or environments, but instead it might be better to think of each class as describing the *columns* of a *normalized* data base table. Update the values in the appropriate table, rather than modeling complex nested relationships.